# Https в Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, http, https

Пытаюсь подключить аутентификацию на сайт через Facebook. Но Facebook использует протокол https, а laravel http.
Как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: поставь LetsEncrypt на VDS, или если shared хостинг, включи в панели хостинга (большинство хостеров это пожжерживают)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel не имеет никакого отношения к протоколу передачи данных, если вы подключите SSL сертификат - Laravel будет на https.

Comment: Проблема в том, что сайт располагается на локальном сервере

Answer (score 0):

Нет проблемы поставить самоподписанный сертификат и использовать его во время разработки. Если локальный сервер [OSPanel](https://ospanel.io) для винды, то он из коробки поддерживает самоподписанные сертификаты, надо только в браузере подтвердить безопасность сайта.
Если [homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead) используешь, там тоже самоподписанный сертификат уже есть.

Исходя из вышесказанного, если используешь OSPanel или homestead, то тебе остается только открыть свой проект в браузере по `https://` и внести сертификат в исключения браузера